# Why can't I enter the wordpress admin interface?

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, setcookie

I accidentally changed the url of my wordpress page, which I finally managed to restore in phpmyadmin, the first page of my website works, but the second page doesn't, and I can't even log in to the admin interface because it throws this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ValueError: setcookie(): "path" option cannot
> contain ",", ";", " ", "\t", "\r", "\n", "\013", or "\014" in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hh\wp-login.php:481 Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hh\wp-login.php(481): setcookie('wordpress_test_...',
> 'WP Cookie check', 0, '/hh\r\n/', '', false) #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\hh\wp-login.php on line 481
> This is the part of the code: if ( SITECOOKIEPATH !== COOKIEPATH ) {
> setcookie( TEST_COOKIE, 'WP Cookie check', 0, SITECOOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, $secure );
> }

I looked to see if I had hit something there, but no. I've also tried to replace it with a code copied from github, but that doesn't work either.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Wordpress has [a dedicated Stack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com) these days. You might do better asking there.

Comment: The SITECOOKIEPATH constant appears to contain the value `/hh\r\n/`, which does not really make sense for a cookie path. Depending on whether your site is a multisite or not, that constant appears be be based on either the `siteurl` option (single site), or `$current_network->path`. You'll have to check how whichever one of this it is, gets that wrong value in the first place.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. i wrote this in the siteurl's domain http://localhost/hh . Whatz should i correct in it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Suddenly I was getting the error of cookies path in the admin page.
I have downgraded the PHP version from 8.0 to 7.3 and it's working for me.

Thank you